# UCanAccess seems unable to read OLE Object column using getBytes()

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess, jackcess

I have a quite large `.mdb` access database I want to convert to SQLite3 to use it under Linux.

I am unable to transfer any of the `BLOB`s (mostly containing images) I have.
Here is a sample test program:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class prova {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                String url = "jdbc:ucanaccess://data/BookDB-201810.mdb";
                try {
                        Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
                        PreparedStatement ps;
                        ResultSet rs;
                        String q = "SELECT * FROM PersonImage";
                        ps = c.prepareStatement(q);
                        rs = ps.executeQuery();
                        while (rs.next()) {
                                byte[] i = rs.getBytes("Image");
                                String fn = String.format("data/img/i%05d.%d.jpg", rs.getInt("PersonId"), rs.getInt("Index"));
                                try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fn)) {
                                        fos.write(i);
                                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                        }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
}
```

Program runs without errors, but the produced files are "strange" (surely not images):

```
$ ls -l i00072.1.jpg 
-rw-r--r-- 1 mcon mcon 369 Nov 23 11:38 i00072.1.jpg
$ file i00072.1.jpg 
i00072.1.jpg: Java serialization data, version 5
```

Looking int them I find this:

```
....sr..net.ucanaccess.jdbc.BlobKey...........L.
columnNamet..Ljava/lang/String;L..keyt..Ljava/util/HashMap;L.   tableNameq.~..xpt..Imagesr..java.util.HashMap......`....F.
loadFactorI.    thresholdxp?@......w.........t..PersonIDsr..java.lang.Integer.⠤...8...I..valuexr..java.lang.Number...........xp...
Ht..Indexsr..java.lang.ShorthM7.4`.R...S..valuexq.~.  ..xt..PersonImage
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**
Since my aim is to convert a book database (maintained on the net as .mdb using the obsolete program [BookCAT](https://www.fnprg.com/index.html) for historical reasons) I found [AccessConverter](https://github.com/clytras/AccessConverter) which seems to fit the bill; unfortunately there are essentially two problems with that:

- In my database some columns are named "Index", which is a reserved word for SQLite (and others, but apparently not for MS-Access); this is trivially fixed inserting a filter "Index" -> "Idx".
- There is a translation `switch (type) { case xxx: ...` to convert the various MS-Access types to more conventional SQLite3 types; breakpointing on the `default:` label I discovered (as @ErikvonAsmuth correctly guessed) there are unhandled `OLE` types. I have no idea about how to handle those.

In the program (BookCAT) those fields contain two kind of data:

- images
- formatted text

The latter is less important because there's always a duplicate "plaintext" version (it would be nice to retrieve also the formatted version, but...).

I would really like to be able to extract the images, though.

In image data there is a companion "ImageType" column invariably set to "2" which (if I'm not mistaken) means they should be `.jpeg` images.

What can I do to retrieve `OLE` data in a usable format?

**Note:** `AccessConverter` does not use `ucanaccess`, it uses directly the underlying `com.healthmarketscience.jackcess` lib instead.

**Note2:** it seems `BookCAT` is built using Delphi, if that is relevant.

Comment: There's no such thing as a `VARBINARY` in Access. There are OLE objects, but those come in many types, some just containing a file as binary data, others containing specific headers, and others compressing files and putting multiple files in a single row. Unless you specify exactly what you're trying to import, we likely won't be able to help you.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth: just a few minutes ago I discovered You are absolutely right. I will update Question to reflect my findings and refine question (short summary: those fields contain either images or "formatted text").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that, in my specific case, all "OLE" fields are actually BLOBs, unrecognizable as OLE2 objects.

In this condition jackcess returns a `Enum OleBlob.ContentType.UNKNOWN` Type and, in this case, it will refuse to access BLOB content (`OleBlob.content.getBytes()` returns `null`).

In order to access stored data is necessary to use directly `Column.getBytes(name)` (completely bypassing OLE subsystem).

Why, in this condition, `ucanaccess` returns an invalid value, instead of failure, is beyond me (probably I should file a bug report; comments welcome).

Image data is plain jpeg-formatted file, while the "formatted text" seems some custom serialization of Delphi `TRichText` widget I don't know how to parse, but that is another issue.

Using `jackcess` `Column.getBytes(name)` I was able to retrieve the data I needed.

Answer (score 1):

With UCanAccess you need to use `ResultSet#getBlob`:

```java
String q = "SELECT * FROM PersonImage";
ps = conn.prepareStatement(q);
rs = ps.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    java.sql.Blob image = rs.getBlob("Image");
    String fn = String.format("C:/Users/Gord/Pictures/i%05d.%d.jpg", rs.getInt("PersonId"), rs.getInt("Index"));
    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fn)) {
            fos.write(image.getBytes(1, (int) image.length()));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We were able to access the content using UCanaccess + accdb file type:

```
String columnLabel = "FIELD1"; 
Object obj = rs.getObject(2);
net.ucanaccess.complex.Attachment[] attachments = (net.ucanaccess.complex.Attachment[])obj;
net.ucanaccess.complex.Attachment att = attachments[0];
System.err.println("Attachment Name: " + att.getName());
byte[] bytea = att.getData();
```

As you can see the attachments is an array and it can hold more than 1 attachment.